# cannot seem to delete key from AWS 3S using javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to delete a 'folder' called `js` from an Amazon AWS S3 bucket. I've followed numerous tutorials and the Identity I'm using has `AmazonS3FullAccess` permissions.

By all I've gathered, the following should work - but it doesn't. I get no errors, I merely get console output of `{}`.

I have a method that can upload to Amazon S3 using the same credentials, so I know they check out right. This is a listing of how the credentials are configured on my `IAM`;

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is the actual code I'm trying to run to delete the content;

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config = {
    'accessKeyId': `{HIDDEN}`,
    'secretAccessKey': `{HIDDEN}`,
    'region': `us-east-1`
};
var rmAWS = function() {
    var BUCKET_NAME = `{HIDDEN}`; var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    var params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: 'js'
    };
    s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
}

rmAWS();
```

Comment: if it returns `{}` its most probably that he has done the job - wait for some minutes (half an hour max) to be reflected in the UI

Comment: I thought that too, but it never changes. I can also still retrieve the files it was supposed to delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS S3 doesn't understand the concept of directory. So, when you try to delete **js** it looks for a file who's key is js. The reality is that there are several files who's keys are **js/foo**. You should try deleting all those files, that the "folder" will be "deleted".

To do so, you should use the deleteObjects method (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObjects-property).

You can't delete objects using a wildcard such as **js/***, but you can list the objects in the bucket and then create an array with only the ones you want to delete.

Try using the listObjects method (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property). Assign the prefix to **js/** that it should only return the objects you'd like to delete. Then use this result as the array for the deleteObjects method.

Comment: I've tried that too, by telling it to delete key `js/*`. Is there a different method I should use?

Comment: @Ciel, just updated the answer. I don't think deleteObjects supports wildcard. Try getting all objects and creating an array with the actual keys that you'd like to delete.

Comment: Yes, actually. I was. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are there multiple "js" "folders" that need to be deleted? Or just one?

```
    var params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: 'FOLDERNAME/FOLDERNAME/js/'
};
```

Make sure to try it out with listing the objects instead of deleting them first.